# ADOConnection cant get table names on SQL LocalDB

Tags: sql-server, delphi, localdb, adoconnection

I have a SQL Database MDF file , I want to connect to that file with ADOConnection and SQL Client 11.0 as provider

ADOConnection connects successfully but there is no Table !

`ADOConnection.GetTableNames()` returns `""`

My code is like this :

```
 ADOConnection1.ConnectionString := 'Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;User ID="";Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial File Name="";Server SPN="";'
               +'AttachDbFileName="G:\Projects\Delphi\Pasargad Insurance\DB\Main.mdf";';
 ADOConnection1.Connected := True;

 ADOConnection1.GetTableNames(REdit.Lines);
```

When I connect to Database with SQL Server Managment Studio, tables are exists

**Edit** :

I removed "Initial File Name" and now the ADOConnection failed to connect :

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file "G:\Projects\Delphi\Pasargad Insurance\DB\Main2.mdf" failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share

I switched tracing of LocalDB to off, copied my database file and deleted main database with SQLServer Managment Studio , and tried again to connect but the same error shown.

Comment: For start I would try to remove `Initial File Name` from the connection string as it seems to be mutually exlusive with `AttachDbFileName`.

Comment: I removed Initial file name and now ADOConnection fails ! , it seems the adoconnection not connected to my file , it was connected to initial file that when i removed this option , it fails to connect ! , I will edit my question with more details ...

Comment: Try to add `User Instance=True;` in the connection string.

Comment: Can you connect the database add designtime? If yes then copy the connectionstring of the TadoConnection into the code. When I connect thesql server I don't use the attachdbfilename.

Comment: `...or it is located on UNC share.`  So... is it?  Is your `G:` drive a network share?  If it is, use the full UNC path instead.

Comment: I've converted your error message image to text - this is helpful for a number of reasons (searchability being among the most important).  You can always copy the text of a message dialog by pressing `ctrl+c`.